# The merchant's account is not able to process transactions with activemerchant + Ruby on rails + Paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

want to parse a payment with PayPal using active merchant I did all the setting but response get the error like this if anyone can help me out then its great thanks in advance :)

> Response

```
======response===========#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x00000000061820d0 @params={"timestamp"=>"2019-02-27T12:29:37Z", "ack"=>"Failure", "correlation_id"=>"21a7f98432854", "version"=>"124", "build"=>"46457558", "amount"=>"10.00", "amount_currency_id"=>"USD", "message"=>"This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.", "error_codes"=>"10548", "Timestamp"=>"2019-02-27T12:29:37Z", "Ack"=>"Failure", "CorrelationID"=>"21a7f98432854", "Errors"=>{"ShortMessage"=>"Invalid Configuration", "LongMessage"=>"This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.", "ErrorCode"=>"10548", "SeverityCode"=>"Error"}, "Version"=>"124", "Build"=>"46457558", "Amount"=>"10.00"}, @message="This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.", @success=false, @test=true, @authorization=nil, @fraud_review=false, @error_code=:processing_error, @emv_authorization=nil, @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil}, @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>==========
```

**

> Error: This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is
>   not able to process transactions.

**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to contact PayPal to get this error addressed. If you look here: https://support.picnet.net/hc/en-us/articles/114094053611-Understanding-PayPal-Website-Payments-Pro-error-messages under error ID 10548 it says the account is not setup as a business merchant account.